# Add a favorite option in the all site "tab"?

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks, stack-exchange

When I am trying to change from one Q&A site to another one, one of the methods I use is to go to the upper left corner click on StackExchange, choose all sites and then the one I want.

I use very few option compared to the ones available and would find it very useful if In could favorite the somehow or even better order them!

Thanks in advance!

Trufa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's *exactly* what you were looking for, but tag sets do cover this .. sort of.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/tag-sets-on-stack-exchange/